# Focus EditText and ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, search, focus, android-edittext

I have within my app, a search functionality. The search box is a basic EditText box with an OnTextChangeListener attached. Below the search box, I have a ListView which displays the results of the search query. Results are displayed as the user begins to type in the search box.

The problem I'm faced with is that the keyboard covers my ListView hence the user cannot see the search results unless the keyboard is hidden. This happens because the keyboard will appear just below the EditText box.

One possible solution is to place the search box below the ListView but is it not aesthetically feasible. The other is to encapsulate both entities with a ViewGroup in an attempt to have the keyboard push up beneath, hence the ListView and the EditText box are visible. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Check ` android:windowSoftInputMode=["adjustUnspecified",
                                       "adjustResize", "adjustPan"]` in the manifest. Try adjustUnspecified for this activity

Comment: I do have those flags...the keyboard will appear just below the EditText box whilst blocking the ListView...I need to see the ListView too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Not the greatest but I simply moved the PageLayout up by adjusting the Y co-ordinate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take scrollView and in the scrollView,put your editText and listView just like:

```
<ScrollView . . .>
    <EditText . . . />
    <ListView . . . />
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it will help you with your problem.

Comment: This may just work, but I don't see how it helps the keyboard push up underneath the ListView and not just the EditText box...guess I'll have to try and see.

Comment: it will be underneath the listview...just try this code, it might help you.